# gmapping missing spots

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

For our robot, slam gmapping have been configured.  However, when we display our cost maps in rviz, we see a big gapping hole that isn't being mapped

[screenshot http://www.muredblade.com/images/screenshot%20from%202013-05-22%2017_24_43.png](http://www.muredblade.com/images/screenshot%20from%202013-05-22%2017_24_43.png)

I know that there are quite a few parameters that can be set for [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping).

Are any of these parameters responsible for this hole in our mapping?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63278/gmapping-missing-spots/) by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the SICK LMS lidar you can set the "use_rep_117_" global parameter to "false" to force it to report readings in legacy format instead of using Inf/NaN. It seems that the gmapping package rejects Inf/NaN values.

Use this information in combination with the maxRange and maxUrange suggestion that Ben has offered.

---

Originally posted by [marcusrm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4960/marcusrm/) with karma: 106 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the maximum range of your laser scanner and what is the reading it gives if there is no object in range of the beam?

I think the problem is, that space where no echo is received by the scanner, is not marked as free. Have a look at the documentation of the `~maxRange` parameter and try the proposed setting `maxUrange < maximum range of the real sensor <= maxRange`. But as far as i know, this depends on the scanner reporting readings of max range and not zero or NaN for beams where no echo is received.

If this does not solve your problem, maybe you could post a small bag file, so we can have a look for our own. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that marking areas with no measurements received to be free can be risky in some cases, as you effectively don't know if things are out of range, or there's something in front of your LIDAR that the sensor just can't see (and that being the reason for getting no returns). The latter is a real possibility for some combinations of LIDARs and surface materials in the environment.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3